# Как узнать размер массива, переданного в функцию?

Tags: c, массивы, функции, указатели, char

Есть массив:

```
char* items[] = {
  "Item 1",
  "Item 2",
  ...
};
```

Как правильно передать его в функцию, чтобы в ней можно было получить размер этого массива, используя `sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0])`?

В данной реализации можно получить элемент массива `itemsArr[i]`, но `sizeof` всегда возвращает 4:

```
void func(char* itemsArr[]) {

}
```

Comment: Никак, передавать размер отдельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что когда вы передаете массив функцию:

```
void func(char *items[]);

char *items[] = {
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    ...
 };

func(items);
```

вы фактически передаете *указатель на первый элемент этого массива*, поэтому вся информация о размерности массива теряется и в функцию не попадает.

---

Есть несколько решений этой проблемы (не претендуя на полноту):

1. **Передать размер массива дополнительным аргументом.** Чаще всего в таких случаях размер массива просто передают дополнительным параметром:

   ```
   void func(char *items[], size_t n);
   ```
2. **Обернуть массив в структуру.** Можно обернуть массив в структуру и в ней хранить его размер:

   ```
   struct Items {
       char **items;
       size_t n;
   }
   ```

   Можно также использовать [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member):

   ```
   struct Items {
       size_t n;
       char *items[];
   }
   ```
3. **Использовать специальное значение в качестве терминатора.** В стандартной библиотеке языка C есть соглашение, по которому все строки заканчиваются на т. н. *нуль-терминатор* — символ `\0`. Именно поэтому нам не нужно явно передавать размер строк в функции типа `strlen` или `strcat`.

   Такой же прием часто применяется и в вашем случае: просто считайте, что достижение элемента со значением `NULL` означает конец массива:

   ```
   void func(char *items[]) {
       for (size_t i = 0; items[i] != NULL; ++i) {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   Конечно, этот способ подойдет только если никакой элемент `items` не может равняться `NULL`.